# ActiveRecord is checking for user in the database after the user was destroyed, resulting in 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a destroy method in my UserController in ActiveRecord.

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
    token = issue_token({ user_id: @user.id})
    render json: { user: @user, jwt: token}, status: 201
   else
    render json: {message: "Username is already taken" }, status: 400
   end
  end

  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   render json: {user: @user}, status: 201
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user == current_user
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    render json: {user: @user}, status: 201
   else
    render json: {message: "Unable to update"}, status: 400
   end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user == current_user
    @user.destroy
    render json: {message: "Your account was deleted"}, status: 200
   else
    render json: {message: "You cannot delete this account"}, status: 400
   end
  end


private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:username, :password, :image_uri, :description, :email, links: [])
   end

end
```

Every time I go to send a delete request to my rails API ActiveRecord does delete the record but then at the end it is looking for the user again.

```
Started DELETE "/api/v1/users/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-30 15:18:32 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#destroy as JSON
Parameters: {"username"=>"pam", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"pam", "id"=>"8", "user"=>{"username"=>"pam", "email"=>"pam"}}
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(1.4ms)  BEGIN
UserFollower Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "user_followers".* FROM 
"user_followers" WHERE "user_followers"."follower_id" = $1  [["follower_id", 8]]
Story Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "stories".* FROM "stories" WHERE "stories"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 8]]
SQL (1.7ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 8]]
(2.2ms)  COMMIT
User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 414ms (ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)
```

I thought it might have something to do with my active record associations?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 validates_presence_of [:username, :email, :password_digest]
 has_secure_password
 has_many :user_followers, class_name: "UserFollower", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
 has_many :followers, through: :user_followers
 has_many :stories, dependent: :destroy
end
```

this is the stack trace:

```
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:189:in `find'
/Users/Josh/dev/mediumrare-rails/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:27:in `current_user'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:30:in `serialization_sco
pe'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:43:in `block in get_seri
alizer'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:43:in `fetch'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:43:in `get_serializer'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:61:in `block (2 levels)
in <module:Serialization>'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:149:in `block in _render_to_body_with
_renderer'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:306:in `each_key'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:306:in `each'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:145:in `_render_to_body_with_renderer
'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in rend
er'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime
'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
/Users/Josh/dev/mediumrare-rails/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:34:in `destroy'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-cors-1.0.2/lib/rack/cors.rb:97:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
/Users/Josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: *Might* be helpful to see your controller.

Comment: it would be really helpful to see a stack trace for the not found error, that will tell you what is causing it.

Comment: It looks like you’re letting the current user destroy their account. Could it be that whatever you’re doing after  the user is deleted is looking to set the current user again (which no longer exists)?

Comment: Yeah I just can't figure out why active record is running another query for the User after the fact. I've used this same pattern for deleting comments and stories in other parts of the project with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your application is looking to load the current_user again.  try setting current_user to nil after a successful delete.

```
def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user == current_user
    @user.destroy
    @current_user = nil
    render json: {message: "Your account was deleted"}, status: 200
   else
    render json: {message: "You cannot delete this account"}, status: 400
   end
  end
```

Comment: It looks like current_user is getting called internally in the render block - if you move the render before the destroy it might work as well

Comment: That works! Still curious why render would need to look up the user though.